# Noir and Lein under Eclipse

Tags: clojure, leiningen, noir

I am trying to use CCW + lein for clojure devl. I built a small Noir app which has page for / 
with command line lein run , I am able to see the output at localhost

But how to run within CCW + Lein under eclipse , I press Run , and then open the browser
, it is not working .. ? What's the problem ? How to debug within Eclipse the web app. ie test
whether the server is running , any other web related debugging ? 
Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the application from the Eclipse REPL. Open the context dialog (right-click), navigate to Clojure and then click Load-file in REPL. After which write `(-main)` (or manually `(server-start ...)` in the REPL.

I mainly use Emacs for Clojure development so there is probably a better way to achieve this.